# Which has better manuscript attestation in Luke 6:9?

Tags: luke, textual-criticism

The KJV with Strong's concordance has the following for Luke 6:9 (word in question is emboldened):

> Then said Jesus unto them, I will ask you one thing; Is it lawful on the sabbath days to do good, or to do evil? to save life, or to **destroy (G622)** it?

The reference *G622* is the Greek word *apollumi* and stems from the verb *ollumi*.

An online searchable interlinear dictionary has *apokteino* in that same place and stems from the verb *kteino*.

This interlinear dictionary has the following to say about it's source material:

> Our free online interlinear New Testament parallels the King James
> Version with the Greek Byzantine Majority Text. The parsing of the
> Greek text is based on the Robinson and Pierpont 2000 edition

Most English translations render the word in question as "destroy" however there are some few that render it as "kill", among those is Young's Literal.

This appears to be a meaningful variation as it actually changes the meaning of the text somewhat.  *Apollumi* means something closer to "to put out of the way entirely, abolish, put an end to ruin" while *apokteino* means something more like "to condemn to death"

Is there a viable textual variant that contains *apokteino* or does it come down to a preference choice between the Byzantine Majority Text, Critical Text, and Textus Receptus?

- By viable variant is meant a variant that has a chance of representing the original

Comment: Robert Young states in his prefaces to his Literal Translation that he follows the Textus Receptus and his preference would be a _translation_  of the same text as the KJV not a preference of variant. Beza, Stephanus and Elzevir are all identical in Luke 6:9, see [Tetus Receptus Bibles](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/42006009). The Byzantine Majority, see same reference, varies.

Comment: @Nigel So YLT translates *Apollumi* as kill where KJV translates it as destroy?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that in Luke 6:9 there is a disputed text of the last word of the verse.  Is it:

- ἀπολέσαι (destroy) as per UBS4, UBS5, Nestle 1904, NA27, NA28, W&H, SBL, THGNT, Souter NTG, NIVGNT, TR, etc, or
- ἀποκτεῖναι (kill) as per Majority text, Byzantine text, Orthodox text, F35, etc?

For more information about which MSS support which reading see NA28 and Pickering's GNT according to F35.  Let me summarize the results by immediately saying that almost all the early MSS before the 5th century support ἀπολέσαι (destroy) and most after that time support ἀποκτεῖναι (kill).  More specifically,

- ἀπολέσαι (destroy) is found in P4, Sinaiticus, B, D, W, etc.
- ἀποκτεῖναι (kill) is found in A and the Byzantine tradition, etc

This is why NA28 has the text it does and why the majority and the Byzantine text has its text.  Almost bizarrely, the Textus Receptus sides with NA28 in this case.